# MVC error page controller and custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have modified my routing to include the culture in the URL

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en-GB", controller = "StyleGuide", action = "Template", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = @"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}" }
        );
```

I have also created `ErrorController` and defined my error pages in `Web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>
```

I am also using mvcSiteMapProvider, so I have included my new error pages and am able to access them via the menu as it uses a URL that includes my culture: `localhost/en-GB/Error/NotFound`

When an exception is thrown the error pages aren't being found because the culture is missing from the redirects defined in `Web.Config`.

How can I include the culture when redirecting to my error pages?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good article describing the possibilities and limitations about error handling approaches in ASP.NET MVC: [Exception Handling in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC#handleerrorvsapperror)

If you don't need a controller or action level exception handling, you can do the error handling in the `Application_Error` event. You can turn off custom errors in the web.config and do the logging and error handling in this event (including the redirection to the correct page).

Something similar to that:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();

    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;  

    string action = string.Empty;    

    if (httpException != null)
    {
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                // page not found 
                action = "NotFound";
                break;
            //TODO: handle other codes
            default:
                action = "general-error";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO: Define action for other exception types
        action = "general-error";
    }

    Server.ClearError();

    string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;    

    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}/error/{1}", culture, action));
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this soon and get back to you - thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to them so promptly